# Entity Framework Navigational property record moving from one record to another "Wait operation timed out"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

I'm getting headaches from this simple function in my Entity framework repository.
I've done similar things a million time, but this one just keeps giving me a **WIN32Exception the wait operation timed out**

Individu (1 - *) Gifts

Somehow i expect that I can't migrate the gifts from Individu to another because i'm looping over the same set that i'm altering.

I checked sys.dm_tran_locks and this doesn't show any running locks on either table in sql.

```
   public void MigrateDataForInd(Individu from, Individu to){
        foreach (var item in from.Gifts.ToList()) {
            to.Gifts.Add(item);
            //also tried: item.Individu = to;
        }
        this.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Any ideas on how to circumvent this issue? (increasing the lock time out period doesn't help, and i'm getting the same error when using other navigational properties (gifts is just one of them)

**UPDATE:**
To give you guys an image of the amount of data i'm dealing with here:

There are +- 500.000 INdividus, and a total of +- 10 million gifts.
Each individu has between 0 and 100 gifts

Do you consider this reason enough to move this code away from EF and run the migrations in an update query? (from the above data you can see that i'm only updating 100 rows in one transaction, and that already gives me the timeout)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve my question to make it easier to answer welcome. .. really need a solution to this.

Comment: Check your tables for triggers / cascades

Comment: There are no triggers or cascades, only some foreign keys and indexes on those FK's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeroen was almost there :)

It should be remove.

```
public void MigrateDataForInd(Individu from, Individu to)
{
    var offlineGifts = from.Gifts.ToList();
    foreach (var item in offlineGifts)
    {
        from.Gifts.Remove(item);
        to.Gifts.Add(item);
    }
    this.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> here are +- 500.000 INdividus, and a total of +- 10 million gifts.
>   Each individu has between 0 and 100 gifts
>
> Do you consider this reason enough to move this code away from EF and
>   run the migrations in an update query? (from the above data you can
>   see that i'm only updating 100 rows in one transaction, and that
>   already gives me the timeout)

Absolutely! You'd need to have a **very** compelling reason to get all that data out of the database to be later sent back. The difference in performance is huge.

As for the original question, something looks very wrong, which is another reason to go directly to SQL in this case. If you run into trouble with the updates, look into the execution plan and it may get you closer.

Comment: +1 for the second part of your comment, i'll try to do it manually and get back to you later

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this:

```
 public void MigrateDataForInd(Individu from, Individu to){
        var offlineGifts = from.Gifts.ToList();
        foreach (var offlineGift in offlineGifts ) {
            from.Gifts.DeleteObject(offlineGift );
            to.Gifts.Add(offlineGift );
        }
        this.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Or maybe call SaveChanges in the second foreach loop ?

Comment: DeleteObject doesn't exist for me on EntityCollection, maybe that's something for another version of EF, I then tried just deleting it from db.Gifts.DeleteObject but that also didn't work ,smth about deleted state, thanks anyway +1 for pointing tom in the right direction,

Answer (score 0):

Incresing time out time will not resolve this,

there is problem with code, Dont use  .Tolist(),
I have modified above code, try it, may it help you

```
 public void MigrateDataForInd(Individu from.Gifts, Individu1 to){
        foreach (var item in from.Gifts) {
            to.Gifts.Add(item);            
        }
        this.SaveChanges();
     }
```

I am considering here Individu is list object which having another list Gift

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already tried this. Since to.Gifts.Add(item) modifies the from.Gifts collection this gives an exception saying I can't modify the collection. ToList resolves this issue.

Comment: It's the other way around, you're supposed to have the ToList as Mvision experienced.